# How to select min value from orders?

Tags: sql

I would like to ask how can I select min value and join two tables.
I have tables orders and goods. I would like to select goods.id and goods.name where value of the order is the lowest.

I've written smth like this

```
 SELECT MIN(orders.value), 
        goods.id, 
        goods.name 
   FROM goods inner join 
        orders ON goods.id = orders.good_id
```

I get values but they are not correct, have no idea whats wrong.

Comment: Please provide data structure of your tables, example data, and what the results you are getting now and what they should be.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: when using *aggregate* function (like `MIN`) you should either put the other fields (`id` and `name`) within aggregate functions as well or provide `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 1):

If this "select goods.id and goods.name where value of the order is the lowest" is indeed what you want...
Try this:

```sql
 SELECT g.id
      , g.name
      , o.value
   FROM goods g
   JOIN orders o on o.good_id = g.id
  WHERE o.value = (SELECT MIN(value)
                     FROM orders)
```